# How to save build from Docker Container?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I use Volumes! But smth went wrong.

My web-app config:
[image]

> And if I use `volumes: -"../web/build:/web/build"` it doesn't work.

My NGINX config:
[image]

I start `docker-compose up --build` and see that build is complete in /build. I use `RUN ls /build` to check it. All is correct.

But when I check on server (not in Docker) web/build - folder is created, but is empty.

Why? How can I save build to use it in NGINX?

My Dockerfile for web-app:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your dockerfile add name to the first image **builder** for example then use it to copy the files to nginx

```
FROM node:13.13.0 as builder

WORKDIR .

COPY package.json . 
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx

COPY --from=builder /build  /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Do I need to combine NGINX and Node in one file? Or is it only for copy files?

Comment: node image will only be used for building the app, and then copy to nginx , node image will no longer be used after that